# Button invisible upon applying basic custom style - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a button visualized by a PNG (no borders, gradients, whatever).

What I did is:

- resources

  ```
  <Style x:Key="PlainImageButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                  <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
  ```
- XAML

  ```
      <Button Width="16" Height="16" Style="{DynamicResource PlainImageButton}">
                  <Button.Background>
                      <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/pencil.png"/>
                  </Button.Background>
          </Button>
  ```

But the button is invisible

[image]

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the supplied background in your template, e.g. like that:

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supplying image as a Background in the button. Whereas in your template you have not used the background property to bind with ContentPresenter

try this

```
 <Button Width="16"
                Height="16"
                Style="{DynamicResource PlainImageButton}">
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="pencil.png" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

Here, I have set the content as the image which will be bind with ContentPresenter in your template

Hope it helps :)